# Java HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object[]>> how to add an empty array?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Im using HashMap in my application and sometimes I need to add a key (String) with a null value (emty array list of objects). But Netbeans 7.4 says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.Version.main(Version.java:35)
Java Result: 1
```

to this code:

```
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object[]>> d = null;

        ArrayList<Object[]> a;
        a = new ArrayList<>();

        d.put("key1", a);
```

I dont want to use a MultiMap. Is there any other way how to solve it easily?

Comment: You haven't initialized `d` to an instance of `HashMap`. You're trying to call `put` on a `null` reference.

Comment: d is null! Please add row d = new Hashmap<String, ArrayList<Object[]>>

Comment: Just initialize d, for example `d = new HasMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Map<String, List<Object[]>> d = new HashMap<String, List<Object[]>>;
List<Object[]> a = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
d.put("key1", a);
```

If d is null, then -> NullPointerException ;)

Answer (score 5):

You're getting a `NullPointerException` because `d` is `null`, and you try to de-reference it with your call to `d.put("key1", a)`.

You can fix this by changing your initialization of `d` to

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object[]>> d = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object[]>>();
```

Now that `d` isn't null, you can use the methods native to `HashMap`, like `d.put("key1", a)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `map.put` without creating an instance of it at first, your map is still null.

You need to instantiate it first:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Object[]>> d = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object[]>>();
```

and then:

```
d.put("key1", a);
```

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object[]>> d = null;
```

and then you try to put element to a null:

```
d.put("key1", a);
```

You must first declare instance of HashMap:

```
 HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object[]>> d = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object[]>>();
```